# ADAL Authentication Requires Device managed

Tags: ios, objective-c, azure, azure-active-directory, adal

I've setup a Demo app for ADAL Authentication. Our company request the InTune app installed: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/intune-company-portal/id719171358?mt=8

After the installation and the setup of InTune, I've installed the demo with ADAL that i've developed:

1. added ADAL as Pod Library
2. added redirect URI inside my Azure Portal (https://portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_AAD_IAM/ActiveDirectoryMenuBlade/RegisteredApps) (one with schema://bundle_id and one with msauth://code/schema%3A%2F%2Fbundle_id)
3. added to app's info.plist:

   ```
   <key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
   <array>
       <string>msauth</string>
   </array>
   ```

4.added to app's info.plist

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Editor</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
        <string>bundle_id</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>schema</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

5. added `[_authContext setCredentialsType:AD_CREDENTIALS_AUTO];` to use inTune App Portal for broker auth.
6. create the authentication with:

   ```
   ADAuthenticationError *error = nil;
    _authContext = [ADAuthenticationContext authenticationContextWithAuthority:@"https://login.microsoftonline.com/common" error:&error];  
   [_authContext setCredentialsType:AD_CREDENTIALS_AUTO];

   [_authContext acquireTokenWithResource:@"https://graph.microsoft.com"
                             clientId:@"my_client_id"                          // Comes from App Portal
                          redirectUri:[NSURL URLWithString:@"schema://bundle_id"] // Comes from App Portal
                      completionBlock:^(ADAuthenticationResult *result)
   {
      NSLog(result.accessToken);
    }];
   ```

Application will correctly prompt microsoft authentication to the user, that is redirected on microsofth authentication on the company page, but after the Authentication, this is the result:

[image]

Comment: Is your device managed? I.e. does it show under "Devices" in the Comp Portal app?

Comment: Yes, It's showed

Comment: And the device shows as "in compliance"? What happens if you tap "enroll now"?  Do you get an error that the device is already enrolled? This is a conditional access failure. You should get your AD admins to see what conditional access policies have been applied to the graph endpoint and your application id

Comment: @Paulw11If I press the button an HTML page with the button that opens the AppStore on Intune will appear

Comment: @Paulw11 the same AD application is used on Android without problems

Comment: Is the "enrollment required" page shown in your app or in the Authenticator app?  I have compared your code against code I have in Swift and yours looks correct. Have you added a keychain sharing group for com.microsoft.adalcache? I don't think not having that would cause this problem though.  Does tapping "more details" provide any useful information?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179864/discussion-between-paulw11-and-alessio-crestani).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Azure AD to determine that a device is managed in order to satisfy conditional access requirements, you must use *Brokered Authentication*.  This is enabled by specifying `AD_CREDENTIALS_AUTO` (which you have done), adding `msauth` to `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` (which you have done) and configuring the appropriate callback URI scheme for your app (which you have also done).

The broker that will be used is the [Microsoft Authenticator](https://itunes.apple.com/au/app/microsoft-authenticator/id983156458?mt=8) app.  If you don't have this installed (which the ADALios framework determines by checking to see if there is an app that responds to the `msauth` url scheme) then the ADAL library will default to showing the login form in a web view in your app.

Since your app cannot determine whether the device is managed, you get the "authentication successful but your device isn't enrolled" result.

Once you install the Microsoft Authenticator app, you will see that it is opened in response to the authentication request.  This app can determine the enrolment status of your device and you should then be returned to your app with a successful token.

The requirement to install the authenticator app could be called out more explicitly in the library documentation, but it is mentioned:

> [**Brokered Authentication**](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-objc#brokered-authentication)
>
> If your app requires conditional access or certificate authentication (currently in preview) support, you must set up your AuthenticationContext and redirectURI to be able to talk to the *Azure Authenticator* app.